# Alternate reasons for 403 error

Tags: php, git, permissions

I have a Linux VM set up that is using apache and PHP to serve web pages locally. Just today I am getting 403 errors on everything within a particular directory in my public folder.

Visiting localhost/dir1 in my web browser works fine (it contains an index.php file), but visiting localhost/dir2 does not work

They are modded identically: 711 for directories and 644 for PHP. Running ls -l from the command line results in:

```
drwx--x--x 17 user group 4096 Feb 18 02:16 dir1
drwx--x--x 17 user group 4096 Feb 18 02:16 dir2
```

When I move a file from dir2 to dir1, it magically works. Dir2 has a few hundred files, but I've gone through all of them to make sure that they are all modded 711 for directories and 644 for php files.

Every folder, directory, and file in dir2 triggers a 403 Forbidden error.

One difference between the two is that I am using Git on dir2 to sync to a remote repository. Its contents are a clone of a collaborator's work. Another thing to note is that some of the contents of one folder, jpg images, have spaces in their names (careless naming by collaborator).

What else could be causing 403 errors? Can Git cause 403?

Comment: Have you checked your apache config? is there an .htacess file creating some funny allow/deny rules? Have you modified your apache already but forgot to reload the config? Is there an include/require for a file that is currently blocked/missing?

Comment: Thank you so much. I found a hidden .htaccess file that, once deleted, fixed the 403 error. Thank you for your help. I spent 4 hours of my life trying to fix this, and you saved me at least 4 more.